# C# | Regex | How to improve my regex performance

Tags: c#, regex, query-performance

I have a logs files and I want to parse these logs with regex - it's a line comparison one-by-one if meet regex conditions.

The line I'm trying to parse:

```
190326 000117.252|0|0|1221564|21|Beg|Request: http://myurl/services/serviceName [CallId=85aa2407-8ca0-481c-9ece-a772ca789ce0]
```

**What information I want to fetch:**

- threadId = *21 - before |Beg| statement*
- callID = *85aa2407-8ca0-481c-9ece-a772ca789ce0 - the value of callId at the end*

The first regex created by me looks like:

```
(?<thread>\d{2}).*\|Beg.*\[CallId=(?<CallId>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+?)\]
```

And the execution took around ~30-35 seconds.

The Second regex I've used looks like:

```
(?<thread>\d{2})[^|]*\|Beg.*\[CallId=(?<CallId>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+?)\]
```

And the eceution time drop to ~9 seconds.

Could you please have a look at my regex and advise me if there's a possibility to improve the regex to get better execution time?

Thanks in advance,
Dave.

Comment: Just a guess but maybe it would be faster when using string.split. If the index of the columns is fix this would help, too.

Comment: Is it possible to use 2 regexes?

Comment: @Sweeper what do you mean?

Comment: Try using character classes to allow the characters that you want to match instead of `.*` like `(?<thread>\d{2})[0-9| .]*\|Beg[ :/a-zA-Z|]*\[CallId=(?<CallId>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\]` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VeTRaz/1) and perhaps add an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom after |Beg| - every line have different values of the message

Comment: @Thefourthbird Execution time was improved from 9,2s to 8,1s better better, but still taking some time :)

Comment: `\|(?<thread>\d{2})\|.*\[CallId=(?<callId>.*?)\]`. Multiline, Compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use two regexes, use two regexes - one for the thread ID, the other for the call ID.

For the thread ID:

```
(\d{2})[^|]*\|Beg
```

Get Group 1.

For the call ID:

```
CallId=([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)
```

Get Group 1.

On regex101.com, your regex took 269 steps, whereas these two regexes took 141 and 11 steps respectively.

If you are stuck with 1 regex only, you can try making the last `+` greedy:

```
(?<thread>\d{2})[^|]*\|Beg.*\[CallId=(?<CallId>[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)\]
```

This reduced the steps from 269 to 199.

Comment: This solution with 2 regexes it's pretty well. The execution time right now is 2,55s